# What does "this" refer to if object is on the stack?

Tags: c++

Got to thinking about the this pointer (from what I can tell it's not a pointer per se but rather an expression resulting in the address of the object) and started to wonder about what "this" actually refers to when an object is created and destroyed within a function scope? So not created using the "new" operator. So something like this:

```
void Foo()
{
    SomeObject o;
}
```

What exactly happens when an object is created as described above and what happens with "this" when it is?

Comment: The same thing: `this` is always a pointer to the object. Whether it's allocated on the stack or on the heap is irrelevant.

Comment: What do you think is the difference between a pointer and an *expression resulting in the address of the object*?

Comment: @user4815162342 maybe I didn't formulate that very well. My bad.

Comment: Just because it is on the stack doesn't mean it doesn't have an address.

Comment: @MasterBait That was actually an honest question, so I can understand where your confusion comes from. Why do you say that `this` is not a pointer, what else do you think it is? A pointer by definition *is* the address of an object, not (only) something created with `new`.

Answer (score 7):

`this` is a pointer to that object, within the scope of its member functions.

Every object has an address, no matter how it was allocated or what its storage duration is. So, whether or not you used `new` is irrelevant.

You will find, though, that the address of dynamically allocated objects is numerically distant from the address of other ones, because they're typically stored in different places in virtual memory (your "heap" vs "stack" nomenclature).

Answer (score 1):

C pointers are not limited to manualy allocated memory, they can point on any part of the memory. Including zones that are not designed to be used by variables, like the code segment which is the part of memory where the machine instructions are stored to be executed.

You can see pointers as a sort of big indexes of the computer RAM. And the RAM as a big array of bytes.

When you declare an object, like in you example, the compiler take memory somewhere. This memory have its own address (the big index I was talking above) and we can use it like any other memory address.

So, in your case, if you declare:

```
SomeObject O;
```

...then the "this" pointer have the same value as a manualy declared pointer like that:

```
SomeObject 0;
SomeObject *MyThis = &O;
```

Comment: _"Including zones that are not designed to be used by variables, like the code segment which is the part of memory where the machine instructions are stored to be executed."_ Well, no, you can't obtain such a pointer without your program having undefined behaviour. And the question is tagged C++, not C.

Comment: You can get it, but you can not use it. It's easy, indeed... you juste have to cast a function pointer. And it will work both in C or C++. I don't know the use, however.

Comment: No, you may not obtain it _or_ use it. Don't worry, it's a common misconception.

Comment: Hum... you mean that we get memory access violation?

Comment: No, I mean exactly what I said. Your program will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: I don't understand why. I just tested it and it worked fine.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: That's not really accurate either. You most certainly can obtain the address of a function. If you want to keep it, however, you must assign it to a pointer to function type. You can't depend on a pointer to data (even a pointer to void, which can point to any data type) being able to hold the address of a function. Nonetheless, obtaining the address of a function, assigning it to a pointer to the correct type of function, and invoking that function via the pointer can certainly be done without any undefined behavior.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I wasn't talking about obtaining the address of a function. Granted, that is one subset of "the code segment which is the part of memory where.....". My intention was to refer to arbitrary parts of memory not containing objects or functions. I was unclear.

Comment: What made me think about this is the fact that when you want to execute a member function in its own thread you have to pass `this` as an argument. Being that the thread itself is a member. So that kind of made me think about object creation in itself and if that combined with the fact that `this` is passed implicitly to every member function means that the functions doesn't reside within the object itself but are rather referenced by it. Hope this makes sense and that it is ok to ask follow up questions.